# How to establish ppp communication between TI AM335x Linux board and Telit DE910 module

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, ppp, cdma

I'm working with TI MA335x board running Linux in it and want to interface Telit DE910 Dual CDMA module to this board and establish ppp communication between these two to receive data from the network.

I have littile knowledge about AT commands and want to know the procedure to establish ppp communication using linux with Telit DE910 module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this is an old question, but it bears answering as there isn't much documentation on handling cdma floating around. This is from Telit's documentation.

```
Turn on Echo "ATE1" 
Turn on verbose error messages "AT+CMEE=2"
Check software version "AT+GMR" 
Set NAI profile "AT$QCMIPP=0"
Set NAI profile enable "AT$QCMIPEP=1"
Set Mobile IP enable (VERIZON) "AT$QCMIP=1"
Set Data release On "AT#NOTI=11,1"
Set Escape character skip "AT#SKIPESC=1"
Set Socket configuration "AT#SCFG=1,1,0,60,600,50"
Set Socket check "AT#SS"
Set Activate context "AT#SGACT=1,1"
Set Echo server connect "AT#SD=1,0,8000,50.192.174.99,0,0,1"
begin send data "AT#SSEND=1"
wait for ">" and then send your data
send "#26" to escape the send prompt
Set Socket INFO check "AT#SI"
Set Receive data "AT#SRECV=1,99"
Set Socket check "AT#SS"
Set Socket close "AT#SH=1"
Set context close "AT#SGACT=1,0"
```